# SVG does not draw figure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, geojson

I am trying to draw this geojson in a svg but it doesn't work.
If I change the sixth decimal to the first coordinate (value increase by one) if it represents the figure but this is not correct.

What would not be representing well?

```
<svg data-bind="html: acSvgPaths, attr: { 'viewBox': svgPaths }" width="100px" height="100px" style="background: #f3f3f3; width: 100%; margin: 0.5em 0;" viewBox="64.77013751864433 67.7408375870796 0.0041484832763671875 0.004410754101002112"><path fill-rule="evenodd" style="fill:green;opacity: 0.5" d="M64.77013**7**51864433,67.74087805444512 64.7740475833416,67.7408375870796 64.7742860019207,67.74480323649146 64.77013751864433,67.7452483411806 64.77013751864433,67.74087805444512 64.77013751864433,67.74087805444512 64.77013751864433,67.74087805444512Z"></path></svg>
```

It does not return any error

Comment: Your path is really big compared to your viewBox. Presumably it's some tiny part of the image that's not drawn on that you're looking at with such a viewBox

Comment: Is the digit marked by asterisks the one you changed?  Was it originally 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are striking a numerical precision problem.

Most (if not all) 2D rendering libraries use float precision internally.  Precision limits of floats mean that values can change in a significant way.  If we convert your original coordinate value from a double to a float we get:

```
64.77013751864433 (double) ==> 64.770134 (float)
```

But the slightly bigger value

```
64.77013851864433 (double) ==> 64.77014 (float)
```

Note we are not taking into account here the extra transformation that the `viewBox` will cause.  But hopefully you can see how rendering of some elements may be affected when you flirt with the limits of floating point precision.

The fix would be to increase the magnitude of your map coordinates so that you don't have coordinates right at the limit of float precision.

For example, if we multiply all the coordinates by 100, the SVG renders fine.

```html
<svg data-bind="html: acSvgPaths, attr: { 'viewBox': svgPaths }" width="100px" height="100px" style="background: #f3f3f3; width: 100%; margin: 0.5em 0;" viewBox="6477.013751864433 6774.08375870796 0.41484832763671875 0.4410754101002112"><path fill-rule="evenodd" style="fill:green;opacity: 0.5" d="M6477.013751864433,6774.087805444512 6477.40475833416,6774.08375870796 6477.42860019207,6774.480323649146 6477.013751864433,6774.52483411806 6477.013751864433,6774.087805444512 6477.013751864433,6774.087805444512 6477.013751864433,6774.087805444512Z"></path></svg>
```